# VIM for XAML editing

Tags: xaml, vim

Can VIM be used for XAML editing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Throw this line at the bottom of your source file and you should be compatible with VS2008:

```
<!-- vim: tw=120 ts=4 sw=4 et syn=xml : 
-->
```

Comment: "Error detected while processing modelines: E520: Not allowed in a modeline: enc=utf8

Comment: I very much want this to work, but for me it isn't (ubuntu lucid) with the following error: `E518: Unknown option: -->`

Comment: You might have to put it at the top of the file now, since I think vim only checks the last line.  This is the solution for me.

Comment: The reason why it won't work on one line is that the _alternative_ form of the modeline syntax must be used ([ref.](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#modeline)): Insert a `set` and you're all set: `<!-- vim: set ft=xml : -->`.

Answer (score 14):

Add the following to your filetype.vim (this will be in your $VIM/vim72 directory, or you can create one in your own personal .vim directory).  This will tell Vim to automatically set the filetype for xaml files to xml.

```
" Xaml
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.xaml        setf xml
```

Comment: I prefer this solution because 1) it applies to all .xaml files and 2) it won't confuse people who don't use Vim.

Comment: Neovim/Lua: `vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({"BufNewFile", "BufRead"},{
pattern = {"*.xaml"},
command = "setf xml"
})`

Answer (score 3):

Yeap. XAML is really just XML and thus plain text.

Here's a "Hello World" example.

```
<Canvas xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007"  
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <TextBlock>Hello World!</TextBlock>
</Canvas>
```

If you don't already have an XML plugin you may want to try [xmledit](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=301)

Comment: I have xml.vim already installed, but it does not recognize .xaml as .xml. Also it whould be cool to get xaml completion :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want full intellisense etc... An option that may be worth exploring is [ViEmu](http://www.viemu.com/) which brings vim keybindings to visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. For a better experience try out some XML plugins (for folding and such) and turn on syntax highlighting.